# How to run GDB as group with GID bit set

Tags: c, gdb

The title pretty much says it all. I am trying to debug a program which has the setgid bit set for a different group (let's call it group A). I am executing gdb as a member of group B. For the sake of argument, assume that I can't just be added to group A. These are both non root/sudo groups.

When I run the program through the command line, it correctly executes with group A's permissions, but when I run gdb, the program calls getegid, which shows that I am still running as group B. Is there any way to change this so I can run gdb as group A? Again, group A does have the setgid bit set, so, shouldn't gdb be running it as group A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GDB, on most systems, uses [ptrace](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) to control, examine, and modify the target process.

As detailed in the [execve man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/execve), an executable's setuid and setgid bits won't have any effect if the process is being ptraced:

> If the set-user-ID bit is set on the program file pointed to by filename, and the underlying file system is not mounted nosuid (the MS_NOSUID flag for mount(2)), **and the calling process is not being ptraced**, then the effective user ID of the calling process is changed to that of the owner of the program file. Similarly, when the set-group-ID bit of the program file is set the effective group ID of the calling process is set to the group of the program file.

[This is not completely true, though. If the calling process is being ptraced and is running as root, the setuid and setgid bits will be honored.]

This restriction of not honoring setuid and setgid bits on ptraced processes has long been a property of Unix systems, as a security measure, to prevent users from using ptrace to alter the behavior of privileged processes.

If you want the setuid and setgid bits to take effect in traced processes, in general the debugger process needs to run as root or have the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability.

Comment: How do you add the `CAP_SYS_PTRACE` capability to `gdb`?.